# Generate 72 hours of timeslots with 15 minutes of interval in android

Tags: android, date, kotlin, time, calendar

I am trying to generate an array of 72 hours timeslots with 15 minutes of interval but it starts with 00:00 after 24 hours, so basically it prints whole 24 hours timeslots 3 times, but i want to start from `00:15..23:45..24:00..24:45..25:00..25:15..72:00`

I have less experience working with Calendar APIs,

Here is my code,

```
        val start_duration = "00:00"
        val end_duration = "72:00"
        val _start_duration = durationFormatter.parse(start_duration)
        val calenderStartDuration = Calendar.getInstance()
        val calenderEndDuration = Calendar.getInstance()
        calenderStartDuration.time = _start_duration
        calenderEndDuration.time = calenderStartDuration.time.addHours(72)
        while (calenderStartDuration.before(calenderEndDuration)){
            calenderStartDuration.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15)
            val timeStr = durationFormatter.format(calenderStartDuration.time).toLowerCase()
            listBookingDuration.add(timeStr)
        }
```

Comment: I'd consider using `LocalTime` instead of calendar.

Comment: You want 29:00, 33:00, and 72:00 as time-of-day values?

Comment: Never use `Calendar` class. That terrible class, along with `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` etc., was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to create "as many 15 minute slots" that can fit in a 72-hour time span, starting today at midnight... then I'd leverage the power of java.time apis:

This is **naive pseudo-code**, but you get the idea:

```
import java.time.*

fun main() {
        val startTime = LocalTime.of(0, 0)
        val today = LocalDate.now()
        var current = LocalDateTime.of(today, startTime) //use datetime to account for day changes.
        val endDateTime = current.plusHours(72)
        val timeSlots = mutableListOf<LocalTime>()// or LocalDateTime if you need the "date" component as well.
        
        timeSlots.add(current.toLocalTime()) // add the 1st interval
        
        while (current.isBefore(endDateTime)) {
            val newCurrent = current.plusMinutes(15)
            timeSlots.add(newCurrent.toLocalTime()) 
            
            current = newCurrent
        }
        
        println(timeSlots)
}
```

This prints:

```
[00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15, 01:30, 01:45, 02:00, 02:15, 02:30, 02:45, 03:00, 03:15, 03:30, 03:45, 04:00, 04:15, 04:30, 04:45, 05:00, 05:15, 05:30, 05:45, 06:00, 06:15, 06:30, 06:45, 07:00, 07:15, 07:30, 07:45, 08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, 09:00, 09:15, 09:30, 09:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30, 11:45, 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 14:00, 14:15, 14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15, 15:30, 15:45, 16:00, 16:15, 16:30, 16:45, 17:00, 17:15, 17:30, 17:45, 18:00, 18:15, 18:30, 18:45, 19:00, 19:15, 19:30, 19:45, 20:00, 20:15, 20:30, 20:45, 21:00, 21:15, 21:30, 21:45, 22:00, 22:15, 22:30, 22:45, 23:00, 23:15, 23:30, 23:45, 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15, 01:30, 01:45, 02:00, 02:15, 02:30, 02:45, 03:00, 03:15, 03:30, 03:45, 04:00, 04:15, 04:30, 04:45, 05:00, 05:15, 05:30, 05:45, 06:00, 06:15, 06:30, 06:45, 07:00, 07:15, 07:30, 07:45, 08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, 09:00, 09:15, 09:30, 09:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30, 11:45, 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 14:00, 14:15, 14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15, 15:30, 15:45, 16:00, 16:15, 16:30, 16:45, 17:00, 17:15, 17:30, 17:45, 18:00, 18:15, 18:30, 18:45, 19:00, 19:15, 19:30, 19:45, 20:00, 20:15, 20:30, 20:45, 21:00, 21:15, 21:30, 21:45, 22:00, 22:15, 22:30, 22:45, 23:00, 23:15, 23:30, 23:45, 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15, 01:30, 01:45, 02:00, 02:15, 02:30, 02:45, 03:00, 03:15, 03:30, 03:45, 04:00, 04:15, 04:30, 04:45, 05:00, 05:15, 05:30, 05:45, 06:00, 06:15, 06:30, 06:45, 07:00, 07:15, 07:30, 07:45, 08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, 09:00, 09:15, 09:30, 09:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30, 11:45, 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 14:00, 14:15, 14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15, 15:30, 15:45, 16:00, 16:15, 16:30, 16:45, 17:00, 17:15, 17:30, 17:45, 18:00, 18:15, 18:30, 18:45, 19:00, 19:15, 19:30, 19:45, 20:00, 20:15, 20:30, 20:45, 21:00, 21:15, 21:30, 21:45, 22:00, 22:15, 22:30, 22:45, 23:00, 23:15, 23:30, 23:45, 00:00]
```

You can [try and play with this in the Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/d23bqM8GL).

Now if you want "day2" to print 24:00, 24:15, 24:30, 24:45, 25:00, etc., you'd likely want to keep it as a `LocalDateTime` and leverage the day comparison to know where in the sequence you are; I'm sure you can figure that part out, as you're able to perform date arithmetic operations with Java.Time apis quite easily.

Note this is not the only and perhaps not even the best way, but it's *a* way.

An alternative is to keep an increment and get startTime.plus(increment).
All in all, Java Time APIs are very straightforward.

#### Update

It appears you need a nudge to complete this, so I spent 15 minutes in the playground and came up with a very *naive* solution. Spoiler alert, there's no magic.

You can find the [updated playground with this change here](https://pl.kotl.in/Ilo8IP94f), and play with it.

I'm positive there could be a lot of optimizations and maybe even better ways to achieve this that are more functional. Hopefully the comments are self-explanatory.

invoke it with `transform(list)` and you get a `List<String>` that prints out as:

```
[00:00, 00:15 ...omitted for brevity... 24:00, 24:15, 24:30, 24:45, 25:00 ...omitted for brevity... 70:30, 70:45, 71:00, 71:15, 71:30, 71:45, 72:00]
```

Here's the "transform" function:

```
fun transform(source: MutableList<LocalDateTime>): List<String> {
        val dayMultiplier = 24 //hours per day, duh!
        val initialDay = source[0].toLocalDate()

        val result = mutableListOf<String>()

        source.forEach {
            val time = it.toLocalTime()
            val hour: Int = time.hour
            
            // calculate the number of days between the dates
            val daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(initialDay, it)
            // Calculate the offset of hours based on the day difference
            val hourOffset = daysBetween * dayMultiplier
            //... and add them to the current hour.
            val newHour = hour + hourOffset

            // Add leading zeros (optional)
            val reformattedHour = if (newHour < 10) "0$newHour" else newHour
            val reformattedMinute = if (time.minute <10) "0${time.minute}" else time.minute
            
            // Naively compose the new time
            val newTime = "$reformattedHour:$reformattedMinute"

            result.add(newTime)
        }

        return result
    }
```

#### Update 2

- I think using `Duration` is better (as seen in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71434249/2684)) by [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque).
- This whole thing can (and likely should) be done in the same loop block. Since you naturally create your object there and put it in the list, nothing stops you from adding the extra step of adding the multiplier and storing the string directly. I'd still try to store the durations if the timeline is not tied to a date/time but rather time "intervals" (aka: durations).

The more complete data you save, the easier will be to "transform it" into whatever you need. If all you store from a ZonedDateTime is the number of minutes, for e.g., then you wouldn't be able to get the date from that... but if you saved the whole ZonedDateTime, you could get pretty much anything out of it.

Comment: I am already achieving the same with my current code but thats not what i want.

Comment: Then what is it you want? If you need to display Day 2, 1AM as "25:00" all you need to do is store LocalDateTime (instead of just LocalTime) and then transform your data in one pass...

Answer (score 1):

Use loop and iterate until 72 hours (4320 minutes)and write a logic to get values after 15 min

```
    for (i in 0 until 4321) {
       val remainder = i % 15
       if(remainder==0){
             val hours = i / 60; //since both are ints, you get an int
            val minutes = i % 60;
           listBookingDuration.add(String.format("%02d", hours)+":"+String.format("%02d", minutes))
         }
 }
```

Comment: Hope this will work

Comment: Is there any way achieving it using Calendar class?

Comment: Simple brother just parse all this in Date (HH:mm) format. I will share the code after some time

Comment: @N.Droid You should avoid the Calendar class as much as possible. Use LocalDate and LocalDateTime instead. See here for a few reasons: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/5-reasons-why-javas-old-date-and-Calendar-API-bad.html#axzz7N8ZU2Zgk

Comment: @SiddarthJain if you format (HH:mm) with give you 24hr time format that i want to avoid.

Comment: You can write your custom class to get time in any format you want that's shall not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is confusing, because you seem to be mixing time-of-day with duration values. I will take it as you wrote it literally.

## `Duration`

Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) objects to represent a span of time unattached to the timeline. If the timeline is not involved, do not use any date-time classes.

Be aware that the *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So when incrementing by 15 minutes, we produce a new fresh `Duration` object rather than altering ("mutating") the original.

```java
List < Duration > durations = new ArrayList <>();
Duration increment = Duration.ofMinutes( 15 );
Duration limit = Duration.ofHours( 72 );
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes( 15 ); // First starting value.
while ( duration.compareTo( limit ) <= 0 )
{
    durations.add( duration );
    // Set up the next loop.
    duration = duration.plus( increment );
}

System.out.println( "durations = " + durations );
```

> durations = [PT15M, PT30M, PT45M, PT1H, PT1H15M, PT1H30M, PT1H45M, PT2H, PT2H15M, … PT69H, PT69H15M, PT69H30M, PT69H45M, PT70H, PT70H15M, PT70H30M, PT70H45M, PT71H, PT71H15M, PT71H30M, PT71H45M, PT72H]

I strongly suggest you do *not* present these values in clock time: 00:15 through 72:00. This format is inherently ambiguous and easily confused for being a time-of-day. Instead, use [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) as seen above.

But if you insist, you can create such text.

```java
for ( Duration d : durations )
{
    String text = String.format( "%02d" , d.toHours() ).concat( ":" ).concat( String.format( "%02d" , d.toMinutesPart() ) );
    System.out.println( text );
}
```

```
00:15
00:30
00:45
01:00
…
71:00
71:15
71:30
71:45
72:00
```

---

If what you really want is to to track every 15 minutes of 72 hours, knowing the date and time-of-day where each of those 15 minute increments lands. For this I would use a `Map`, a collection key-value pairings. In your case, the key would be a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object and the value would be a `ZonedDateTime` object to represent the date with time-of-day as seen in a particular time zone. Post another Question, if you want to pursue this route.